# Is there a particular reason why Unity's Graphics.DrawMesh doesn't accept a scale parameter in any of its constructor overloads?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently [Graphics.DrawMesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.DrawMesh.html) has the following constructors:

```
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, int materialIndex);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Material material, int layer, Camera camera = null, int submeshIndex = 0, MaterialPropertyBlock properties = null, bool castShadows = true, bool receiveShadows = true);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation, Material material, int layer, Camera camera, int submeshIndex, MaterialPropertyBlock properties, Rendering.ShadowCastingMode castShadows, bool receiveShadows = true, Transform probeAnchor = null);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Matrix4x4 matrix);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Matrix4x4 matrix, int materialIndex);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Matrix4x4 matrix, Material material, int layer, Camera camera = null, int submeshIndex = 0, MaterialPropertyBlock properties = null, bool castShadows = true, bool receiveShadows = true);
public static void DrawMesh(Mesh mesh, Matrix4x4 matrix, Material material, int layer, Camera camera, int submeshIndex, MaterialPropertyBlock properties, Rendering.ShadowCastingMode castShadows, bool receiveShadows = true, Transform probeAnchor = null);
```

While **position** and **rotation** are exposed, none of the overloads accepts a scale parameter to set the **scale** of the drawn mesh dynamically.

1. Is there a particular reason for this?
2. What's the best way to scale anyway?

Comment: There's been quite a few recent comments on SO that "Unity is Crap" and while I know that is not quite the intent on *these* comments, I want to just add that Unity is very much like PHP; in that it is very powerful when used skillfully but it's also able to be used very unskillfully and so is relatively easy for novices and the great unwashed to make and publish *bad* content. (This is not to say that Unity is perfect, far from it, but it's definitely not as crap as recent StackOverflow posts want to imply)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Matrix4x4.TRS function to create a matrix combining position, rotation and scale, which can then be used in Graphics.DrawMesh. For example:

```
Vector3 position = Random.insideUnitSphere;
Quaternion rotation = Random.rotation;
Vector3 scale = new Vector3(0.5f, 1, 2.5f);

Matrix4x4 matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(position, rotation, scale);

Graphics.DrawMesh(mesh, matrix, material, 0);
```

Comment: After modifying the value of scale, the mesh created by ``Graphics.DrawMesh`` has an offset, comparing the position of the original mesh, why?

Answer (score 2):

Dude when using `DrawMesh` wouldn't you just use the transformation matrix itself to scale it, right?

i.e.,

> 1. Is there a particular reason for this?

you'd likely just do it in the transformation matrix so no need to add a scale command

> 2. What's the best way to scale anyway?

I guess in the transformation matrix